# Display large PDF using iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

I was wondering what is the best way to display a big PDF file (it's a map actually) using  iPhone SDK (the file is around 5MB), because it's really slow in a UIWebView.

I want to be able to scroll through the PDF and zoom in/out.

Also do you think that it would be better to convert it to a PNG?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display the PDF using quartz it is faster, but it requires more code to handle it. You can download the quartz example from Apple.   The only drawback I have seen is that zooming isn't as smooth.